# Json problem in flickr

Tags: php, json, flickr

I have this json but I have no idea how to get 7796249@N02

```
a:2:{s:4:"user";a:3:{s:2:"id";s:11:"7796249@N02";s:4:"nsid";s:11:"7796249@N02";s:8:"username";a:1:{s:8:"_content";s:9:"ilhan.z.y";}}s:4:"stat";s:2:"ok";}
```

Comment: I don't know about Flickr, but that isn't JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a serialized PHP array, not JSON. Use:

```
$array = unserialize('that response goes in here');
```

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using? In Groovy, for example, you would do something like [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/json.html):

`import groovyx.net.http.*
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder',
    module='http-builder', version='0.5.0' )`

def http = new HTTPBuilder( 'http://twitter.com/statuses/' )

http.get( path: 'user_timeline.json',
        query: [id:'httpbuilder', count:5] ) { resp, json ->

println resp.status

json.each {  // iterate over JSON 'status' object in the response:
    println it.created_at
    println '  ' + it.text
  }
}

**Edit after PHP tag added:**

I'm not a PHP guy, but it looks like [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is what you need to use.